# C# Windows application

Tags: c#

how to add columns in C# windows applications

Comment: Add columns to what? DataGridView, ListView, etc

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, but I'm afraid you'll have to post a lot more information before anyone can give any meaningful answer to this question.

Comment: Click on Add Columns

Comment: What is a coloumn according to you or what kindaa coloumn you want ? What purpose should it serve in your application ?

Comment: Like the way you add in C# web application!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for instance a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx), it has a [Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns(v=VS.100).aspx) property ... you can add columns with the [SubItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=VS.100).aspx) property of the ListViewItems. There are other possibilities (controls) for getting columns, though (like the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)).

Maybe you should have a look around (=google) for this components. Any decent book will cover them, too.

Comment: thank you for your subjection

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace WithColumns
{
    public class FormWithColumns : Form
    {
        public FormWithColumns()
        {
            Label label1 = new Label();
                Label label2 = new Label();

            SuspendLayout();


            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.bc.edu/bc_org/avp/cas/fnart/arch/greek/doric1.jpg");
            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);

            stream.Close();

            ClientSize = new Size(img.Width * 3, img.Height);

            label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            label1.Size = img.Size;
            label1.Image = img;

            label2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(img.Width * 2, 0);
            label2.Size = img.Size;
            label2.Image = img;

            Controls.Add(label1);
            Controls.Add(label2);
            Text = "Form With Columns";
            BackColor = Color.White;
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see i need datagridview column

Comment: Maybe you should specify that in your question.

Comment: @Lawrance ask another question which very clearly says whether you're using WinForms or not (your other question asked about ajax), what you want to add a column to, and whether you are talking about design time or run time.  If you ask a silly question, you will just get silly answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Coloumn : Control
{
}

//in your Form Load
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    this.Controls.Add(new Coloumn());
//when the control comes here, your form is flooded with Coloumns..
```

I did it this way, because your `requirements are not clear`.

Comment: ya its' fine to populate column